# Dividing thousands of concurrent https requests into smaller blocks in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency

I am working on a project where thousands of concurrent https calls are made.
My first question is: **Where is the concurrence limit? How many calls can be made concurrently? On what does it depends?** 
Secondly, I work on ubuntu system and in most of the cases, the system hangs because of too many requests. How can i divide these thousands of concurrent requests into blocks of something like 50 or 100 requests at a time and on completion of those, the next set of requests are called.

my code looks like:

```
items.forEach(function(item) {
        request().then(function() {
            if(counter == items.length) {
                deferred.resolve("Success");
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        });
        counter++;
    });
```

Items array is mostly more than 10k.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Promise.map](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) concurrency options in bluebird

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var join = Promise.join;
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs"));
var concurrency = parseFloat(process.argv[2] || "Infinity");
console.time("reading files");
fs.readdirAsync(".").map(function(fileName) {
    var stat = fs.statAsync(fileName);
    var contents = fs.readFileAsync(fileName).catch(function ignore() {});
    return join(stat, contents, function(stat, contents) {
        return {
            stat: stat,
            fileName: fileName,
            contents: contents
        }
    });
// The return value of .map is a promise that is fulfilled with an array of the mapped values
// That means we only get here after all the files have been statted and their contents read
// into memory. If you need to do more operations per file, they should be chained in the map
// callback for concurrency.
}, {concurrency: concurrency}).call("sort", function(a, b) {
    return a.fileName.localeCompare(b.fileName);
}).then(function() {
    console.timeEnd("reading files");
});
```

Comment: This will start sending all the request together right? I want this to be as such that it sends for first 50, till their response is returned next requests are not triggered.

Comment: Yes. They will wait til the previous batch all finish.

Comment: But where i can define that my batch should be of 50 requests?

Comment: Using the concurrency option: `{concurrency: 50}`

Comment: Great. Thanks. I will give this a try.

Answer (score 1):

**Where is the concurrence limit?**

Firstly your all request will go in to the [event loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) and then one by one in to callstack. So there is no actual limit of this it will start eating your RAM when callstack started filling more and more items.

**How many calls can be made concurrently?**

You can use series and parallel model -

Where you can to send 50(any number) request in one slot and then another slot and so on.

To make series and parallel request you can use [async series](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#series) and [async parallel](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel) respectively.

**On what does it depends?**

Watch the link that I have mentioned in first answer.